# Como mudar o stdout de volta para o default?

Tags: c

No caso eu altero o stdin e stdout para alguns .txt especificos, porem depois de alterar nao sei como fazer ele retornar para o stdout normal(no caso o prompt), eu altero por meio do freopen como no exemplo:

```
freopen (fileOutName, "w", stdout);
```

Alguem pode me dizer como fazer o stdout voltar para o prompt?

Comment: Não sei como é sua leitura em Inglês, mas dá uma olhada nesse texto. Nele você vai ver que não é [recomendado o uso de freopen.](http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html)

Comment: Caramba, é a msma pergunta hehe obrgiado pela indicacao ;P